# Android keyboard on top of layout

Tags: android, layout

I want the soft keyboard to be overtop of my layout, not move my layout around when it pops up. How do I do this? I looked in my manifest and i never set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Also, I have several other activities that are almost identical, but work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the default behaviour. You need to explicitly include `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to make it NOT resize the window [see docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a situation with only a RecyclerView in the layout. The default behaviour was adjustResize

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

did the trick